# How to run a custom script as Administrator without password prompt?

Tags: windows, privileges, runas

I have couple of scripts which I need to run as local user call "scriptexec" from Administrator account. So when I tried to run with runas it prompts password for user scriptexec. Is there anyway to run those scripts as local user without prompting password on automation?

Comment: Are you avoiding this because you don't know the password, or because you have to run the same script many times?

Comment: I need to run the same script many times on automation and also I dont know the password. Its verify difficult to get password more then 1000+ servers

Comment: Its going to be really hard to do this without knowing the password. The only thing you can do is to make the script run at user logon, but then the user still needs to login and that means someone who knows the password needs to enter it.

Comment: @Berend why do you think this will work if he can't run the script as the admin user itself?